# gRPC Analog of C # MessageDescriptor Parser in Python

Tags: c#, python, grpc

I am looking for. Analog of C # MessageDescriptor [Parser](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/reflection/message-descriptor#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_reflection_1_1_message_descriptor_1a91daf0cfef7c7dadd77b080774d683bc) in Python.
For example. I am trying port this C# code to Python. But unfortunately in python implementation of MessageDescriptor is not field Parser. How I can get parser in Python implementation

```
foreach (var msg in fd.MessageTypes)
{
    var name = fd.Package + "." + msg.Name;
    TypeLookup.Add(name, msg.Parser);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python,  you can call msg.ParseFromString() directly on the message.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/0adb74c2d36833be37b35a9ab45e4f699a1d645c/python/google/protobuf/message.py#L181